Pie Chart appearing empty in "Viewer"
I'm trying to plot a pie chart using plotly package. this is my data frame.
Dept value
1    A    31
2    B    21
3    C    12
4    D    15
5    E     7
6    F    14

For some reason, it appears empty in Viewer with no errors. I've tried every variation but to no avail. This is what I wrote:
> plot_ly(all_male) %>% 
    add_pie(all_male, labels= ~`Dept`, values=~`value`)


Could be related to this issue. If it is, the solution is to install this patch.

Hi! I guess your dataframe is named all_male? It would be helpful for others if you share all your code.  This code works fine for me (in comments apparently no layout is possible, so you have to layout it yourself):
all_male <- data.frame(Dept = LETTERS[1:6],  value = c(31, 21, 12,15,7,14))
library(plotly)
plot_ly(all_male) |>   add_pie(all_male, labels= ~Dept, values=~value)
